# Notifications in PostgreSQL with Python(psycopg2) does not work

Tags: python, postgresql, triggers, psycopg2, sql-function

I want to be notified when there is a new entry in a specific table `"FileInfos"` in PostgreSQL 12, so I wrote the following trigger:

```
create trigger trigger1 
after insert or update on public."FileInfos" 
for each row execute procedure notify_id_trigger();
```

and the following function:

```
create or replace function notify_id_trigger() 
returns trigger as $$
begin 
    perform pg_notify('new_Id'::text, NEW."Id"::text); 
    return new; 
end; 
$$ language plpgsql;
```

to get the notifications I use the python library [psycopg2](https://www.psycopg.org/):

```
import psycopg2
from psycopg2.extensions import ISOLATION_LEVEL_AUTOCOMMIT
import select


def dblistener():
    connection = psycopg2.connect(
            host="127.0.0.1",
            database="DBNAME",
            user="postgres",
            password="....")

    connection.set_isolation_level(ISOLATION_LEVEL_AUTOCOMMIT)
    cur = connection.cursor()
    cur.execute("LISTEN new_Id;")
    while True:
        select.select([connection], [], [])
        connection.poll()
        while connection.notifies:
            notify = connection.notifies.pop()
            print("Got NOTIFY:", notify.pid, notify.channel, notify.payload)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    dblistener()
```

But unfortunately my python code does not work, what did I do wrong?
BTW: The database and the table were created with the Entity Framework (C#).

Comment: I'm guessing you are having identifier("new_Id") issues.  Try with all lower case to confirm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [NOTIFY syntax](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-notify.html), *channel* is an identifier. That means that `new_Id` in

```
LISTEN new_Id
```

is automaticaly converted to `new_id`. Unfortunately, `pg_notify('new_Id'::text, new."Id"::text)` notifies on channel `new_Id`. You have two options. Change the channel in the trigger:

```
perform pg_notify('new_id'::text, new."Id"::text);
```

or enclose the channel in double-quotes in `LISTEN`:

```
LISTEN "new_Id"
```

The use of capital letters in Postgres can cause surprises.

Comment: The issue with capital letters(especially mixed case) will cause surprises in all(most?) databases if you try to compare quoted identifiers to unquoted ones. The difference is the Postgres issue will be opposite of the SQL standard, fold to lower case instead of upper case in the unquoted situation.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver - I didn't want to blame or slander  Postgres in the least. However, this case is special because it concerns the use of an identifier as an argument to a function.

Comment: Hello @klin ,that solved the problem, thanks again :-)
perform pg_notify('new_id'::text, new. "Id"::text);

Comment: The issue is taking the general case of mixing quoted and unquoted identifiers in SQL and turning it into : "The use of capital letters in Postgres can cause surprises." It can cause surprises in any SQL database(AFAIK) you mix quoted/unquoted identifiers. Postgres decided to stand the problem on its head by doing a 180 on the standard, so that should be noted.

Comment: Hello @Adrian Klaver I wasn't aware of that, thank you for pointing it out :-)